Is the following sentence structure correct? — "How many story a building is it?", "How many person a tent is it?", "How many core a processor is it?"
ell.stackexchange.com:
(1) How many times an increase was it?
The structure of (1) is very interesting to me.
I want to find out whether I understood it correctly or not.
For this purpose, I made up some analogous sentences.
(2) How many story a building is it?
(3) How many person a tent is it?
(4) How many core a processor is it?
Are (2), (3) and (4) also correct?
If not, then why are they not correct, whereas (1) is?

You didn't understand it correctly.  I can't see anything in the linked question to suggest that How many times an increase was it? is a valid sentence. We would ask "How many storeys does the building have?" "How many does the tent sleep?"

Jay's answer says The only way I can think of to get the kind of answer you're looking for would be to ask something wordy, like, "How many times an increase was it? I mean, like was it two-fold, three-fold, four-fold?" But I agree it's not very idiomatic.

How many + countable noun in the plural, always. So 2, 3 and 4 are incorrect. Notice in 1: How many times etc. times is plural.

@Lambie In the phrases "a two-times increase" and "how many times an increase", the word "times" is not a noun, but an adjective.

two-times increase is not How many times does x appear in y? But your 1 is not idiomatic. Also, two-times increase is a noun used attributively i.e. as an adjective. "how many times an increase"=is not grammatical, but times and increase are both nouns. How many times did x increase? is more idiomatic by far.

All the answers so far are (in my opinion) correct, but the OP’s confusion results from a difference between what an adjectival phrase can accomplish in English, and what a copula can.  You can say:

It is a big tent.

or

This tent is big.

but while it is perfectly correct to say:

It is a five-person tent.

it is wrong, or at least heavily discouraged, to say:

This tent is five-person.

Therefore asking “how many person [or persons or people] is this tent?” is not done by native speakers.
Ditto with cores of a processor.  In the case of stories of a building, you absolutely can say:

This building is five stories.

because a building consists almost entirely of its stories.  Although it may also have basements and subbasements, parking, curtilage, and so on, those are not considered essential to its “buildingness”.  There are buildings without basements, but there are no zero-story buildings.
Of course a tent must hold at least one person and a CPU needs a core, but it also must have other things (a roof, an ALU), so we say they “have” rather than “are” these things.

You wrote "This building is five stories" is correct. Would it also be correct to say this without "-s": "This building is five-story" ? Thanks.

@Loviii The number of stories a building has is countable, as are the number of weeks in a vacation, and the number of stars a hotel boasts. But we often use the singular form: "a 40-story high rise building", "a two-week vacation", and "a five star hotel" Note that the singular noun is often hyphenated and acts like an adjective, it qualifies the noun it precedes.

@Loviii — nope, “five-story” is a legit adjective, but you cannot use it in the copula form — or as least it would sound odd to a native speaker.

If "The building is five stories" is correct, then I think "The processor is four cores" is also correct, right? Thanks.

@Loviii — A building is five stories, and (almost) nothing else.  The building consists of five stories.  The most important part of a CPU is its cores (hence the names) but it has a lot of other things.  You would not say “that mall is 12 shops”, because it also has a food court, a bunch of corridors, a parking lot, and so on.

@MichaelLorton I think I understood your explanation. According to it, if we have the phrase "a multi-day tour", we can rephrase it into "The tour is many days", because in terms of duration a tour consists only of days and nothing else. Is this right? Thanks.

@Loviii — yes, I think that is an excellent way to look at it.  The tour is many days; the hike is five miles; the cargo is 10 tons.  The predicate-compliment might not describe the subject entirely, but it measures the subject entirely.

How many x:
How many is always followed by a plural noun. That is actually a grammar point:

How many times did the organizers increase the price?
How many increases in the price were there?
The price increased five times.
How many times did the price increase?
OR
How many price increases were there?

(2) How many story a building is it?
(3) How many person a tent is it?
(4) How many core a processor is it?
See an idiomatic version of 2, 3 and 4.
(2) How many storeys does the building have? [to have x number of storeys]
(3) How many persons/people fit in that tent? [to fit in a tent]
(4) How many cores does the CPU have? [to have a core]
That said, adjectivally, one can do this:

This represents a two-fold increase.
That is a five-storey building.
That is a six-person tent.
That is a three-core CPU.


Another idiomatic version of the question  using the verb BE:

How many stories [alt. spelling storeys] is the building?
How many weeks is the course?
How many years was the (prison) sentence?
How many feet is the tape measure?
How many processors is that new CPU?
How many pages is the book?

This is an informal, conversational construction.
P.S. Why don't your versions work, which have a structure like "how many page a book"?  Because phrases of the "how many page" variety do not resolve to anything grammatical. Such a phrase does not yield the adjective of degree required for constructions like "how big a dog was it?". Nor do they yield the cardinal number required by constructions like "How many years was the sentence?"

1 is not common or particularly idiomatic; there are no Google hits for the question outside of Stack Exchange; but it doesn't seem ungrammatical. To me, 2, 3, and 4 seem worse.
It relates to which verb is most natural to use for describing something.

The building has three stories.


The tent holds three people. (or accommodates, is big enough for, etc.)


The processor has three cores. (or contains, etc.)

So you'd ask

How many stories does the building have?


How many people does the tent hold?


How many cores does the processor have?

In contrast, you'd say

It's three times something else

Or you could say (although I don't think it's very elegant, and people often get confused by statements like this):

It's a three-times increase (or three times increase, or three-fold increase)

So, while it's uncommon, you could say

How many times an increase is it? (or was it)

But I wouldn't recommend it. As the answer you link says, it's not a particularly elegant way to ask. People often get confused whether "increased three times" means by an additional three (hence four times bigger than the original) or three times bigger. You would do better to ask something like:

How big an increase was it?

Or

What did it increase by?

And then someone can explain it as clearly as possible.

Yes, as you say How many times an increase was it? is uncommon, and I'd say ungrammatical.

Or "How many does the tent sleep?" (how many is there sleeping space for?).
